# Master Method: We want a big 'd'?

Tags: algorithm

According to the Master Method, algorithms run faster if the "rate of work shrinkage" is greater than the "rate of subproblem proliferation."

But the "rate of work shrinkage" is b^d where d represents the amount of work done outside the recursive calls. This suggests that we want to increase the amount of work done outside the recursive calls, which sounds counter-intuitive.

This suggests that, if we identify a sub-optimal approach for tackling work outside the recursive calls, we'll actually identify a faster algorithm.

Where is my thinking flawed?